# Why is it considered dangerous to use the -execdir + argument with the find command?

Tags: find, security

> "Like `-exec`, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in which you started `find`.  This is a **much more secure method for invoking commands**, as it avoids race conditions during resolution of the paths to the matched files."
>
> "As with the `-exec` option, the `+` form of `-execdir` will build a command line to process more than one matched file, but any given invocation of command will only list files that exist in the same subdirectory.  If you use this option, you must ensure that your `$PATH` environment variable does not reference the current directory; otherwise, an attacker can run any commands they like by leaving an appropriately-named file in a directory in which you run `-execdir`."

When you run the `-execdir` command using the `+` method, why does it make you vulnerable to attack if someone puts an aptly named file in your `PATH`?  Is it because it's possible that that executable will be run instead of the expected executable?  Sort of like in Windows 7 when you replace `sethc.exe` with a renamed `cmd.exe` to access `cmd.exe` from the login prompt, except in this case it's run by find thinking the command it's running is `/usr/bin/ls` for example, when it's really running something else named `ls`?

If that's the case I guess one just needs to check sum the command and make sure the entire path is specified when running such a command.

I suppose the other version with `;` would be volunerable to that as well correct?

Comment: direxec? execdir?

Comment: The "much more secure method" refers to `-execdir +`, which is, I presume, the (missing) heading of the quoted text.